# JS-скролл вправо

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код на js, если размер окна ниже 1200, появившийся скролл ставился с правой стороны, а не левой по стандарту. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(40000, 0); // для ширины сайта не более 40000 пикселей
```

Comment: чего-то не получается (=

Comment: Скролл - это который scrollbar? Если да, то сомневаюсь, что это возможно, так как это зависит от браузера.  
Если же вы ставили какой-то плагин, кастомизирующий скролл, то, пожалуйста, укажите его.

Comment: не аплагин не ставил скролл браузера